# Intellij Compose Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, android-jetpack-compose

Whenever I run my app this appears, any idea on how to find to make the change?

I understand I have to change it with the recommended one, but I can't find where

*** MESA_GLSL_CACHE_DISABLE is deprecated; use MESA_SHADER_CACHE_DISABLE instead ***

I've looked around but no luck

Comment: Can you attach a link to your project?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't find much searching online, only Firefox / Linux related issues, but nothing for Kotlin Multiplatform.

Since it's *only* a deprecation warning, I wouldn't bother much who or why it's showing. It could be caused by an internal library / SDK part which is still using a deprecated library and might be updated in the future.

If you really need to remove the warning, you can mark the function / piece of code causing the warning with the [@Deprecated](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-deprecated/#:%7E:text=Marks%20the%20annotated%20declaration%20as,property%20level%20could%20be%20used.) annotation.